# give background image to canvas and then clip area

Tags: jquery, html, css, canvas, fabricjs

i want to clip canvas as well as give background image , can i give background to whole canvas  and then clip area??

I want to set background image , and then clip area to circle where i can draw image.

```
 canvas.setBackgroundImage('images/tee.png', canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
 canvas.clipTo = function (ctx) {

      var path = new fabric.Circle({
                radius : 40,
                fill : 'red',
                left : 55,
                top : 55
            });
    path.render(ctx);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$( "#Bird" ).click(function() {
$('.canvasid').css("background-image", "url(images/bird.jpg)");
$('.canvasid').css("background-size", "cover");
$('.canvasid').css( "background-repeat", "no-repeat");
});
```

Comment: this i have tried but when i save canvas only clip part is saved , background image is not saved.

Comment: hey simmi have you been sort out the canvas shape problem and background image problem i am facing same issue when i converting to canvas to image. @simmisimmi